# Can't access database from SQL Server Management Studio Express and causes the machine to freeze?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

Sometimes I cannot access the databases in SQL Server Express (installed in same machine) via the MSSMSE.

[image: DB nodes are not accessible!]

I have to restart the machine to get this corrected.

Other thing is **very** slow responsiveness of SSMSE! Management Studio itself is very slow and it slows down other applications as well! The computer works fine until SSMSE is opened, and start to freeze after it is open. I found the same issue expressed by many people in the [SQL Server Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/4bb541d3-2370-40c6-b25c-ffbc038d0ee9/). The solutions suggested there didn't work for me!

This happens even if the only running application is SSMSE.

Has anyone encountered similar problems? more importantly, got any solutions/ explanations?

Comment: You already cropped the image - couldn't you crop it to the top too - a bit too long, don't you think? There, done it for you.

Comment: I wanted to show I was running MSSMSE only (not too many apps at the same time, which might cause the the freezing).

Comment: A short sentence to that effect would be better - don't force people to scroll. And most people will _ignore_ that bit in the picture, as you didn't highlight it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens to be a hardware problem! Got solved by 'error fixing' the hard disk.